# Prelude: How to add smartparens key bindings to C-c prefix?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, prelude, prefix-keys, clojure

I am using Emacs with Prelude. When I hit `C-c` prefix in a clojure buffer, I would like to show a smartparens key bindings. Like in screenshot below I would like to to add entry for smartparens key bindings, just like  `C-c-,` shows `cider-test-command-map` How can I do this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong (new to emacs, coming from vim) a keymap is a set for key bindings,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to define a new prefix key, say `C-c z`, for `cider-mode`, binding it to a smart-parens keymap.

Assuming that `smart-parens-mode-map` is that keymap, and assuming that `cider-mode-map` is the keymap that defines `C-c` as a prefix key, you can do this:

```lisp
(define-key cider-mode-map (kbd "C-c z") smart-parens-mode-map)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will start from here.